# using variable in $_POST[]

Tags: php, string, variables, post, array-key

I suppose that this is very noob question but I can't figure it out.

I've got code:

```
for($i=1; $i<9; $i++){

    if (isset($_POST['is'$i'ID'])) {
        echo $i . " is OK<br>"; 
    }


}
```

And I know that the problem lies in this line :

```
if (isset($_POST['is'$i'ID']))
```

How can I use variable i in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) rules apply even when used as array keys:

```
if (isset($_POST['is'.$i.'ID']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply concat your strings. You even do it in your echo call :)

```
if (isset($_POST['is' . $i . 'ID']))
```